# strings.xml special characters in multilingual

Tags: android, multilingual, polish

Hey, 
I've developed an application with french and english translation.
A guy sent me the strings.xml in polish language and in UTF-8 format (cause there are many characters i can't read).
I can open it with notepad with no problem, but Eclipse replace all the special characters by another one (a sort of square)
an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the encoding on a per file basis in Eclipse by selecting the properties of the file. Specify the correct file encoding from the dropbox. (in your case UTF-8)

you can also specify a default encoding in the eclipse preferences (content types).

Answer (score 0):

Put symbol code in string tag:

```
<string name="">Welcome &#33;</string>
```

Output will be look like: Welcome !

For more symbol code use below link :

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

Enjoy...